# Extract string from text

Tags: c#, .net, substring

I has a string like TPHSFL100 and TPHFL50.  For the first string, i want get FL100, for second string i want get HFL50.  How I can do this?  I do not know which text user will key in, any dynamic solution for this or what algorithm I should use?

Comment: And what have you tried? Can you show your code?

Comment: Will the codes always end with a number?

Comment: What are the rules for knowing what to fetch?

Comment: are you want last 5 character from any string ???

Comment: @StianStandahl - the code mostly will end with number.

Comment: @DarshanPatel - Not last 5 character, it is depend.

Comment: Then please state your requirements more clearly.

Comment: The FL100 and HFL50 is a unique code from database where I can compare and select the record.  I think I find a way to do this.  Just separate the digit and alphabet.  Then substring the alphabet and combine with the digit and select from database to check whether exist or not.  If exist, just stop looping.

Answer (score 0):

```
string text = "ABCDEF";
string sub = text.Substring(text.Length-5,text.Length);
Console.WriteLine("Substring: {0}", sub);
```